# Convert a webm video to avi one using python and gstreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer

I wanna code a gstramer pipeline in python to convert a webm video into avi one.

I made the pipeline to display the webmvideo, which works. 
How to perform what I want?
I though that just adding a "x264" element to the video queue and "lame" to the audio one, was sufficient. 
I noted that a mux is necessary and I aded that. 
What I get is:

`gst.element_link_many(self.queuev, self.video_decoder,colorspace,x264enc)
gst.element_link_many(self.queuea, self.audio_decoder, audioconv,lame)
gst.element_link_many(avimux,filesink)`

where there's a specific function to use the audiodecoder and videodecoder which is:

`def demuxer_callback(self, demuxer, pad):
        if pad.get_property("template").name_template == "video_%02d":
            qv_pad = self.queuev.get_pad("sink")
            pad.link(qv_pad)
        elif pad.get_property("template").name_template == "audio_%02d":
            qa_pad = self.queuea.get_pad("sink")
            pad.link(qa_pad)`

I think I've to code something similar for avimux. 
And I've done this:

```
 def avimux_callback(self, avimux, pad1):
    if pad1.get_property("template").name_template == "video_%02d":
        qv_pad1 = self.queuev.get_pad("sink")
        pad1.link(qv_pad1)
    elif pad1.get_property("template").name_template == "audio_%02d":
        qa_pad1 = self.queuea.get_pad("sink")
        pad1.link(qa_pad1)
```

but I get an error about the filesource and the script doesn't works. 
Suggestions??
Thanks
FrankBr

Comment: I suggest testing it using gst-launch first before writing a Python script. To convert to AVI use something like this `... ! x264enc ! avimux ! filesink location=test.avi`.

Comment: Also provide debug output of your script using `GST_DEBUG`

Comment: @Dejan I coded: gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=video.webm ! matroskademux name=demux ! queue ! vp8dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! textoverlay text="ciao" !  x264enc ! avimux name=mux ! filesink location=newfile.avi demux. ! queue ! progressreport ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! lame ! mux.
but I got (when I get played the file):

`gsttypefindelement.c(954): gst_type_find_element_activate (): /GstPlayBin2:play/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstTypeFindElement:typefind:
Can't typefind empty stream
`

Comment: I got it. The pipeline which I used:
`gst-launch-0.10  filesrc location=video.webm ! decodebin2 name=decoder ! queue ! audiorate ! audioconvert ! legacyresample ! lame ! mp3parse ! queue ! muxer. decoder. ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! queue ! matroskamux name=muxer ! filesink location=file.mkv `

I used matroskamux instead of avimux.